# In Ruby on rails How to get a response data in API GET request by removing double quotes

Tags: json, ruby, api

How to get the response without double quotes?

Below is my API code developed using Ruby on Rails. When I pass the data as `test123`, I am getting response as `"test123"` but I need the output as `test123`.

```
desc 'get API'

get '/test_api' do     
 params[:from_number]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to render it as plain text? Something like this in your controller method:

```
def get_api:
     render plain: params[:from_number]
end
```